# Response when re-buying managed in-app-product or requesting RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS

Tags: android, google-play

I am testing in-app-billing in my game on Android. I am able to purchase the managed products and i get the expected response from the server. However when I try to re-buy the managed product or request RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS I don't get a response.

When re-buying I do get the popup message titled "Item already purchased", but then there's no response. So that I can re-unlock the purchased items, I should be getting a response should i not? Even in testing with a test account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't make it clear how/why you're attempting to re-buy the managed product. Did you uninstall/reinstall your app and then try to restore/re-buy it? Or did you just click "buy" again after clicking "buy" the first time?

The Google-provided BillingService/ResponseHandler is designed to only call you back in `onPurchaseStateChange`. That means that if you just bought the product, nothing has changed, so there's no callback.

However, if you clear the data of the app (using Manage Applications settings panel, or by uninstalling/reinstalling the app fresh), you should get `onPurchaseStateChange` callbacks when you RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS. If not, I'd guess that there's a bug in your code.

Comment: Thanks for this, this was driving me nuts! I has always assumed that we had to use `onRestoreTransactionsResponse` but that never made any sense since it provides no specific information.